# how to show selected rows in to the another uitableview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

Can anyone solve my problem.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        if([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]){
            [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"selectedIndexPaths1 :%@",self.selectedIndexPaths);
        } else {
            [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];        
            NSLog(@"selectedIndexPaths2 :%@",self.selectedIndexPaths);          
        }

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];    
    }
```

How to pass selected rows(selectedIndexPaths) in to another view controller and that tableview(view controller) shows only selected rows?

Comment: Su paras bhai.. aava que karo chho?

Comment: how to pass selected rows(selectedIndexPaths) in to another view controller and that tableview(view controller) shows only selected rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new view controller

```
MyNextViewController *myNextViewController = [MyNextViewController alloc] init];
```

have a method in the next view controller which takes the parameters of selectedIndexPaths.

```
[myNextViewController setIndexesOfRowsToPresent:self.selectedIndexPaths];
```

and in the new view controller, assuming you have the data model which is used to populate the table, use this to do the necessary.

Or else, in the original view controller instead of created an array of selctedIndexPaths, create another array of data to be presented in the next view controller and pass along that array. That way, you need not do any manipulation in the new view controller. You just pass the data to be shown and on viewWillAppear, it will automatically show the table correctly.

```
[myNextViewController setData:mySelectedDataArray];
```

or even better have it in the alloc init of the new view controller.